# Google API python convert object to json

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm new to google apis after spending the last 5 years dealing with Boto3 in AWS.

My problem is the following code snippet:

```
from google.cloud import resource_manager

def main():

    client = resource_manager.Client()

    # List all projects you have access to
    for project in client.list_projects():
        print(project['name'] + "" + project['status'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, for those in the know - you know that **project** is a Project object, not a dict. And therefore i cannot access it's children this way.

I tried to convert project using json.dumps(project) but it claims that it's not serializable. I toyed with flask and jsonify, but that's just too much overhead for a simple script to list projects and the status of them. This is one of many scripts i'll need to write. So i need to find a clean way to convert these types of objects to json format.

Here is what a Project object actually looks like:

```
project = {Project} <Project: 'remove label' ('sys-1234')>
 full_name = {str} 'projects/sys-1234'
 labels = {dict: 0} {}
 name = {str} 'remove label'
 number = {str} '571234'
 parent = {dict: 2} {'type': 'folder', 'id': '561234'}
 path = {str} '/projects/sys-1234'
 project_id = {str} 'sys-1234'
 status = {str} 'ACTIVE'
```

Can someone lend a hand? I've been spoiled with the very well written and easy to work with Boto libraries for the last few years. Struggling with this one.

Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you manually craft some code, you cannot completely convert a class to json. Some classes have objects that are not serializable.

The Resource Manager object has a dictionary property `__dict__`

```
{
    '_client': <google.cloud.resource_manager.client.Client object at 0x000002A6391A89D0>,
    'project_id': 'mystic-advice-090909', 
    'name': 'Mystic Advice', 
    'number': '999999999999', 
    'labels': {}, 
    'status': 'ACTIVE', 
    'parent': None
}
```

You can get a close approximation by processing the dictionary:

```
j = project.__dict__
j2 = {}

for k in j:
        if isinstance(j[k], str):
                j2[k] = j[k]

print(j2)
```

Which results in:

```
{
    'project_id': 'mystic-advice-090909', 
    'name': 'Mystic Advice', 
    'number': '999999999999', 
    'labels': {}, 
    'status': 'ACTIVE', 
    'parent': None
}
```

Note: my simple loop is not processing children that are themselves dictionaries. You would need to add additional code for those cases. Example `if isinstance(j[k], dict):`

If you want to get creative, you can extend the Project class with a method to convert the object to JSON:

```
def to_json(self):
        j = self.__dict__
        j2 = {}

        for k in j:
                if isinstance(j[k], dict):
                        j2[k] = j[k]
                if isinstance(j[k], str):
                        j2[k] = j[k]
        return j2

resource_manager.project.Project.to_json = to_json

client = resource_manager.Client()

for project in client.list_projects():
        print(project.to_json())
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i figured since i got that serialization error. I was trying to find something light-weight to convert, but no dice.